# GooglePlayServices update deprecates DFP ads?

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services, google-dfp

I have a DfpAdView that I'm using according to the documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/fundamentals#android

I've been using the GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.  I just updated Google Play Services to version 13, and it seems that the AdMob SDK has been integrated into Google Play Services in this version.  However, DFP is not supported as mentioned here:

https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/ads.html

> **Note:** The SDK doesn’t currently support DFP, Ad Exchange or Search Ads for Mobile Apps but support is coming soon.

I have to use GooglePlayServices for the Maps SDK, but it breaks the required DFP ad that I'm using.  Do I need to remove the DFP ad in favor of something else, or do I change the build order so that the AdMob jar takes precedence over the GPS library where package/class names conflict (is that possible?)

Comment: just dont reference any of the play services ad classes and still use the old admob jar file

Comment: @tyczj For one, the project won't build that way.  The namespaces clash so the build process fails with the "Conversion to Dalvik format failed" message.  And, since the namespaces are the same, how would my class know which one I was referring to in my import statement?  The point is that they took the same classes and changed them and put them in the same library I depend on for Google Maps

Comment: they have the same classes but they do not have the same package references ie. the admob jar is `com.google.ads.AdView` and the play services is `com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView` so they are not the same. I was able to build just fine with having the admob jar and the new google play services in my app before i moved over to the new admob in google play services

Comment: @tyczj You are probably unaffected by the change because you're using AdMob's AdView.  I, for business requirements, need to use the DoubleClick "Dart for Publishers" DFPAdView (as mentioned above).  This has been removed temporarily (notice the quoted text from their website "support is coming soon"), so the ad I was using is hosed.  The business requires DFP ads because that's what we are using on web, mobile web, and iOS and that's where all our tracking and sales are.

Comment: as of January 9th 2014, DFP is supported in Google Play Services

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for now (if you are using DFP and one of the other Google Play services) is to excise the Admob classes from the Google Play Services library and use the Admob-6.4.1 SDK.

Not ideal, but I suspect DFP support will be delivered soon.

Alternate is t hold off on upgrading to the new GPS library until DFP support is available. Depends on your urgency.

Comment: what do you mean by "excise the Admob classes from the Google Play Services library and use the Admob-6.4.1 SDK", and how would I do that? I have both libraries now

Comment: Open up the Google Play Services library and delete the Admob classes from it. Then you can safely and happily use the Admob classes from Admob-6.4.1.

Comment: google play services library is a compiled JAR file, how do you just delete classes and recompile?

Comment: AS jar file uses the zip file format. Use a zip editor like WinZip, open up the Jar file and delete the classes. Then uses the modified Jar file in your classpath.

Comment: thanks, as of January 9th Google Mobile Ads does support DFP in Google Play Services, the google mobile ads website has not updated this fact